# How to see account address in another function in Javasript

Tags: javascript, blockchain, solidity, metamask

The account address is getting displayed on the console properly when initializing but showing undefined when calling console.log(account) from other functions. Here is my code.

```
var account;
window.addEventListener('load', async () => {
    if (window.ethereum) {
        window.web3 = new Web3(ethereum);

        ethereum.autoRefreshOnNetworkChange = false;

        const accounts = await ethereum.enable();
        account = accounts[0];
        console.log(account); //here the account working properly.
    }
});

var contractaddress = '0x26708Df214A65Dda444E61266642e6650F4e8923';

function get_request_details() {
    console.log(account); //here it is showing undefined
}
window.onload = get_request_details;
```

Comment: when you call your function `get_request_details`? Maybe you are calling before setting the value of the account variable.

Comment: @Mateen i have edited the code and added a line of code  at the end which i had forgotten earlier while writing the question. Please recheck.

Comment: Asynchronous 101. You are eating your pizza before it is made and delivered to your house.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was arising because the function was running before the initialization can be done and that is why I modified the code as follows.

```
var account;
window.addEventListener('load', async () => {
    if (window.ethereum) {
        window.web3 = new Web3(ethereum);

        ethereum.autoRefreshOnNetworkChange = false;

        const accounts = await ethereum.enable();
        account = accounts[0];
        console.log(account); //here the account working properly.
        get_request_details();
    }
});

var contractaddress = '0x26708Df214A65Dda444E61266642e6650F4e8923';

function get_request_details() {
    console.log(account); //here it is also working
}
```

I called the function from the async event only so that when the initialization will be done after than only the function should run.

Answer (score 0):

I don't see the contractaddress variable used anywhere. So here is my opinion.

```
const get_request_details = function(account) {
    console.log(account);
}

const run_after_window_loaded = async function() {
    if (!window.ethereum) {
        return false;
    }
    window.web3 = new Web3(ethereum);
    ethereum.autoRefreshOnNetworkChange = false;

    const accounts = await ethereum.enable();
    console.log(accounts);

    if(accounts.length > 0){
        get_request_details(accounts[0]);
    }
}

window.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', async function(event) {
    await run_after_window_loaded();
});
```